# Opening Browser Instances from different Vendors

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser, hta

I know the subject is a little bit weird, but I have given it because I got a requirement for my client to open IE instance from Chrome browser.

I know this question has been asked many times, but since it's my client requirement I can't ignore. They have upgraded the application on latest browser but one of the functionalities is still only supported by IE browsers only. 
I know one way I can do is to create a HTA file and open the default browser but still it's a big pain to integrate HTA in javascript(Please let me know if any ideas). Also creating ActiveXObject for WScript.Shell in Chrome browser is pain.

Please guide me how can I impress my client as it's all about my small business.

Thanks

Comment: Did you mean that you want to open a link with a Chrome Browser in HTA ?
Can you edit and post what did you tried so far as code in HTA ?

Comment: What function is only supported by IE? I work on the IE team, and we've been stripping out proprietary stuff left and right - it would be better for your client to find a standards-based approach, than to work out some way to hop around between browsers. What do they expect to happen on machines where IE is not installed?

Comment: @JonathanSampson.. They are supporting for IE so they have installed IE on their machines. They upgraded their application to chrome and in a page, there is a link and on that they want to open the IE browser.

Comment: @s_k_t I understand, but what [feature] in Internet Explorer are they relying on? Because there's a good chance it may have been ripped out of later versions, and a near-certain chance it was ripped out of Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of HTA showing you how to open links with IE, Chrome ,Firefox and with the default browser and how to pass some command line.

```
<html>
<head>
<HTA:APPLICATION
APPLICATIONNAME="Open links with IE, Chrome and Firefox and how to pass command line"
BORDER="THIN"
BORDERSTYLE="NORMAL"
ICON="Explorer.exe"
INNERBORDER="NO"
MAXIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
MINIMIZEBUTTON="NO"
SCROLL="NO"
SELECTION="NO"
SINGLEINSTANCE="YES"/>
<title>Open links with IE, Chrome and Firefox and how to pass command line</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="VBScript">
'************************************************************************************
Option Explicit
 Function Executer(StrCmd,Console)
    Dim ws,MyCmd,Resultat
    Set ws = CreateObject("wscript.Shell")
'La valeur 0 pour cacher la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 0 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /C " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,True)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
'La valeur 1 pour montrer la console MS-DOS
    If Console = 1 Then
        MyCmd = "CMD /K " & StrCmd & " "
        Resultat = ws.run(MyCmd,Console,False)
        If Resultat = 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Success"
        Else
            MsgBox "Une erreur inconnue est survenue !",16,"Une erreur inconnue est survenue !"
        End If
    End If
    Executer = Resultat
End Function
'************************************************************************************
Sub window_onload()
    CenterWindow 480,400
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub CenterWindow(x,y)
    Dim iLeft,itop
    window.resizeTo x,y
    iLeft = window.screen.availWidth/2 - x/2
    itop = window.screen.availHeight/2 - y/2
    window.moveTo ileft,itop
End Sub
'************************************************************************************
Sub Ip_Publique()
    Dim Titre,URL,ie,objFSO,Data,OutPut,objRegex,Match,Matches,ip_public
    Titre = "Adresse Ip Publique !"
    URL = "http://monip.org"
    If OnLine("smtp.gmail.com") = True Then
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        ie.Navigate (URL)
        ie.Visible=False
        DO WHILE ie.busy
            Sleep 100
        Loop
        Data = ie.document.documentElement.innertext
        Set objRegex = new RegExp
        objRegex.Pattern = "\b([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}\b"
        objRegex.Global = False
        objRegex.IgnoreCase = True
        Set Matches = objRegex.Execute(Data)
        For Each Match in Matches
            MsgBox "Votre IP Publique est : "& Match.Value,64,Titre
        Next
        ie.Quit
        Set ie = Nothing
    Else
        MsgBox "Vérifier votre connexion internet puis re-executer ce script",48,Titre
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub

'**************************************************************************************
Sub Sleep(MSecs)'Fonction pour faire une pause car wscript.sleep ne marche pas dans un HTA
    Dim fso,objOutputFile
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim tempFolder : Set tempFolder = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2)
    Dim tempName : tempName = "Sleeper.vbs"
    If Fso.FileExists(tempFolder&"\"&tempName)=False Then
        Set objOutputFile = fso.CreateTextFile(tempFolder&"\"&tempName, True)
        objOutputFile.Write "wscript.sleep WScript.Arguments(0)"
        objOutputFile.Close
    End If
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run tempFolder&"\"&tempName &" "& MSecs,1,True
End Sub
'**************************************************************************************
Sub SSID_names()
Dim objShell,fso,File,strContents,objRegEx,objMatch,colMatches
    set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Executer("netsh wlan show all > Wlan.txt",0) = 0 Then
        Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("Wlan.txt",1)
        strContents = File.ReadAll
        Set objRegEx = New RegExp
        objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
        objRegEx.Global = True
        objRegEx.Multiline = True
        objRegEx.Pattern = """([^""]+)"""
        set colMatches = objRegEx.Execute(strContents)
        For each objMatch in colMatches
            MsgBox "SSID name: " & objMatch.Value,64,"SSID name"
        Next
    End If
End sub
'***************************************************************************************
Function OnLine(strHost)
Dim objPing,z,objRetStatus,PingStatus
    Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_PingStatus where address = '" & strHost & "'")
    z = 0
    Do    
        z = z + 1
        For Each objRetStatus In objPing
            If IsNull(objRetStatus.StatusCode) Or objRetStatus.StatusCode <> 0 Then
                PingStatus = False
            Else
                PingStatus = True
            End If      
    Next    
        sleep 200
        If z = 4 Then Exit Do
    Loop until PingStatus = True
    If PingStatus = True Then 
        OnLine = True
    Else
        OnLine = False
    End If
End Function
'***************************************************************************************
Sub WLAN_Networks()
    If Executer("netsh wlan show profiles > Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show networks >> Wlan_tmp.txt & netsh wlan show interfaces >> Wlan_tmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type Wlan_tmp.txt > Wlan_Networks.txt",0) = 0 Then
        Call Executer("Start Wlan_Networks.txt & Del Wlan_tmp.txt",0)
    End If
End Sub
</script>
</head>
<p>Links List (examples) :</p>
<ol>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start iexplore.exe www.google.com',0)">Lien Google avec iexplore.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe http://bbat.forumeiro.com/',0)">Lien BBAT avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start Firefox.exe www.developpez.net',0)">Lien developpez.net avec Firefox.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.yahoo.fr',0)">Lien Yahoo avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.fr',0)">Lien Autoitscript.fr (Français) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start chrome.exe www.autoitscript.com',0)">Lien autoitscript.com (Anglais) avec Chrome.exe</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="Call Executer('Start www.sfr.fr',0)">Lien SFR avec votre navigateur by default</a></li>
</ol>
<BODY text=white bgcolor="DarkOrange" TOPMARGIN="1" LEFTMARGIN="1">
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=90 lines=15 & Color 0A & Title Ping sur www.stackoverflow.com by Hackoo & Ping www.stackoverflow.com',1)">Ping on www.stackoverflow.com</button><hr>
 <center><button onclick="Call Executer('FindStr /? > HelpFindStrTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type HelpFindStrTmp.txt > HelpFindStr.txt & start HelpFindStr.txt',0)">Help sur FindStr</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('ipconfig /all > configTmp.txt & cmd /U /C Type configTmp.txt > MyIPconfig.txt & Del configTmp.txt & start MyIPconfig.txt',0)">IpConfig</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=50 & Color 9B & Title Hackoo & netstat -a',1)">Netstat</button>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=60 lines=10 & Color 0A & Title Hackoo & arp -a',1)">Arp</button><hr>
 <button onclick="Call Executer('mode con cols=80 lines=30 & Color 9B & Title Tracert vers www.stackoverflow.com by Hackoo & Tracert www.stackoverflow.com',1)">Tracert to  stackoverflow</button><br><hr>
 <center><button onclick="Call Ip_Publique">IP Publique</button>
 <button onclick="Call SSID_names()">SSID WLAN</button>
  <button onclick="Call WLAN_Networks()">WLAN Network</button>
 </center>
 </center>
</body>
</html>
```